# Compile with cmake nmake generator but does not compile with cmake visual studio generator. template instantiation link error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++, cmake, nmake

I work on porting to Windows a Linux C++ project. The buildsystem is cmake (2.8). I successfully built it using the nmake generator (Visual C++ 10) but its debug version does not start (see question 12215163), then I wanted to try it under Visual Studio but here the build fails at link time, not finding a template instantiation coming from a DLL.

You'll find below the outputs of the nmake and visual studio builds Please note that I tried an explicit template instantiation but it made no difference.

CMake and nmake generator (Visual C++ 10, x64, build type = Debug): it compiles

```
c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe    /Zc:wchar_t- /EHsc /GR /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -IE:\Projets\Amose\Sources\lima_linguisticprocessing\src -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include\QtXmlPatterns -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include\QtXml -IC:\Qt\v4.8.2\include\QtCore -IC:\PROGRA~1\boost\BOOST_~1\include -Ic:\amose-debug\include    -D WIN32 -Dlima_lp_analysisdict_EXPORTS -DQT_DLL -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK -DLIMA_ANALYSISDICT_EXPORTING -DQT_DEBUG /TP /FoCMakeFiles\lima-lp-analysisdict.dir\FsaAccessResource.cpp.obj /FdC:\amose-vcbuild\lima-lp-debug\src\linguisticProcessing\core\AnalysisDict\lima-lp-analysisdictd.pdb -c E:\Projets\Amose\Sources\lima_linguisticprocessing\src\linguisticProcessing\core\AnalysisDict\FsaAccessResource.cpp

"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_dll c:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe  @CMakeFiles\lima-lp-analysisdict.dir\objects1.rsp  /out:lima-lp-analysisdictd.dll /implib:lima-lp-analysisdictd.lib /pdb:C:\amose-vcbuild\lima-lp-debug\src\linguisticProcessing\core\AnalysisDict\lima-lp-analysisdictd.pdb /dll /version:1.0  /STACK:10000000 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL -LIBPATH:C:\PROGRA~1\boost\BOOST_~1\lib -LIBPATH:c:\amose-debug\lib lima-common-factory.lib lima-common-misc.lib lima-common-data.lib lima-common-fsaaccess.lib lima-common-mediaticdata.lib lima-common-time.lib lima-common-xmlconfigurationfiles.lib lima-common-processunitframework.lib lima-common-mediaprocessors.lib ..\LinguisticProcessors\lima-lp-linguisticprocessorsd.lib ..\LinguisticResources\lima-lp-linguisticresourcesd.lib "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtXmlPatternsd4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtXmld4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtNetworkd4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtCored4.lib lima-common-misc.lib lima-common-data.lib lima-common-mediaticdata.lib ..\LinguisticProcessors\lima-lp-linguisticprocessorsd.lib lima-common-factory.lib lima-common-time.lib lima-common-xmlconfigurationfiles.lib lima-common-processunitframework.lib lima-common-mediaprocessors.lib lima-common-qslog.lib "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_50\lib\boost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib" C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtXmlPatternsd4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtXmld4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtNetworkd4.lib C:\Qt\v4.8.2\lib\QtCored4.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
```

CMake and Visual Studio generator (Visual C++ 10, x64, debug) : link fails

```
 cl /c /IE:/Projets/Amose/Sources/lima_linguisticprocessing/src /IC:/Qt/v4.8.2/include /IC:/Qt/v4.8.2/include/QtXmlPatterns /IC:/Qt/v4.8.2/include/QtXml /IC:/Qt/v4.8.2/include/QtCore /I"C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_50/include" /IC:/Program /IE:/Projets/Amose/Sources/lima_linguisticprocessing/Files/amosecommon/include /I"C:/amose-vc/include" /Zi /W1 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D _DEBUG /D WIN32 /D QT_DLL /D QT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB /D QT_XML_LIB /D QT_CORE_LIB /D BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK /D LIMA_ANALYSISDICT_EXPORTING /D QT_DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D lima_lp_analysisdict_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t- /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"lima-lp-analysisdict.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"C:/amose-vcbuild/lima-lp-vc/src/linguisticProcessing/core/AnalysisDict/Debug/lima-lp-analysisdictd.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:prompt E:\Projets\Amose\Sources\lima_linguisticprocessing\src\linguisticProcessing\core\AnalysisDict\FsaAccessResource.cpp
```

(Link command line is not displayed in Visual Studio)

```
Création de la bibliothèque C:/amose-vcbuild/lima-lp-vc/src/linguisticProcessing/core/AnalysisDict/Debug/lima-lp-analysisdictd.lib et de l'objet C:/amose-vcbuild/lima-lp-vc/src/linguisticProcessing/core/AnalysisDict/Debug/lima-lp-analysisdictd.exp
2>FsaAccessResource.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl Lima::Common::FsaAccess::FsaAccessReader16<class boost::adjacency_list<struct boost::vecS,struct boost::vecS,struct boost::bidirectionalS,struct boost::property<enum vertex_count_t,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >,struct boost::property<enum boost::vertex_name_t,unsigned long,struct boost::property<enum vertex_text_t,class QString,struct boost::no_property> > >,struct boost::no_property,struct boost::no_property,struct boost::listS> >::read(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?read@?$FsaAccessReader16@V?$adjacency_list@UvecS@boost@@U12@UbidirectionalS@2@U?$property@W4vertex_count_t@@V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@U?$property@W4vertex_name_t@boost@@KU?$property@W4vertex_text_t@@VQString@@Uno_property@boost@@@2@@boost@@@2@Uno_property@2@U52@UlistS@2@@boost@@@FsaAccess@Common@Lima@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void __cdecl Lima::LinguisticProcessing::AnalysisDict::FsaAccessResource::init(class Lima::Common::XMLConfigurationFiles::GroupConfigurationStructure &,class Lima::InitializableObjectManager<class Lima::LinguisticProcessing::AbstractResource,struct Lima::LinguisticProcessing::ResourceInitializationParameters> *)" (?init@FsaAccessResource@AnalysisDict@LinguisticProcessing@Lima@@UEAAXAEAVGroupConfigurationStructure@XMLConfigurationFiles@Common@4@PEAV?$InitializableObjectManager@VAbstractResource@LinguisticProcessing@Lima@@UResourceInitializationParameters@23@@4@@Z)
```

Comment: It seems you're forgetting to include some additional dependencies .lib or dll file

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: well, cmake configuration is the same with nmake and with Visual Studio but it compiles with nmake. And the symbols that are not found are in a library that is linked and used a lot in the other build configuration that link.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I finally was able to compile in Visual Studio. I'm not sure it was already the case when I asked, but this morning I saw that cmake was picking the cygwin linker instead of the Visual C++ one. I corrected and it built. If this iss the answer, it is strange, because several other projects and subprojects linked with no error. Is it possible at all to link successfully with the cygwin linker object files compiled with the MS Visual compile cl ?

Comment: ohh nice, seems like your cmake is very picky/choosy :)

Comment: Do you think I should transform my last comment in an answer ?

Comment: Sure, if it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in a comment. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I'm not sure why, but I finally was able to compile in Visual Studio. I'm not sure it was already the case when I asked, but this morning I saw that cmake was picking the cygwin linker instead of the Visual C++ one. I corrected and it built. If this is the answer, it is strange, because several other projects and subprojects linked with no error.